# Flutter initial route using provider value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I just started using provider as a state management for flutter. I have a value in a provider to be used for the initial login. **isLogin** will return true or false and depending on that it will redirect the user to home or login page. I'm getting the error below:

*Could not find the correct Provider above this MyApp Widget*

Plus, is this a good way of doing authentication or is there a better way. I'm using laravel API for authentication.

**Main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
      create: (context) => UserProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
      initialRoute:Provider.of<UserProvider>(context,listen:false).isLogin?'/':'/login',
      routes: {
        '/':(_)=>HomePage(),
        '/donation-history':(_)=>DonationHistoryPage(),
        '/login':(_)=>LoginPage(),
        '/new-donation':(_)=>NewDonation()
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
      title: 'RedHero',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        accentColor: Colors.white,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        fontFamily: "Poppins",
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(color: kBodyTextColor)
        )
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It's ok, but how about my initial problem? I cant find the error, I check the widget tree and the provider is on top of all my routes @Uni

Comment: the widget above belongs to MyApp @Uni

Answer (score 1):

The broken pattern is:

```dart
class OuterWidget : StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Something>(
      ... Provider.of<Something>(context) ...
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that `Provider.of<Something>` receives the same `context` that was passed to the `build` function. On that context, the `ChangeNotifierProvider` does not exist; the provider is only added to descendant build contexts, which are created while building child widgets.

If that isn't clear, imagine extracting the provided object into a variable (which does not change the meaning of the code):

```dart
class OuterWidget : StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final something = Provider.of<Something>(context);
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Something>(
      ... something ...
    );
  }
}
```

Now it's quite obvious that we're trying to consume an object that hasn't been provided yet.

One solution, then, is to split the inner part into a separate widget:

```dart
class OuterWidget : StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Something>(
      ... InnerWidget() ...
    );
  }
}

class InnerWidget : StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ... Provider.of<Something>(context) ...;
  }
}
```

This widget will receive a new child context, on which the provider does exist.

Another solution is to use a [`Consumer` widget](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html), which exists exactly for this scenario:

```dart
class OuterWidget : StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Something>(
      ...
      Consumer<Something>(builder: (_, something, __) => ... something ...)
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Now, the build of the children of `Consumer` is delayed until the `builder` method, which therefore also receives a build context on which the provider exists.